# consequences of Kuratowski operators

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

*Let $(X,\tau)$ a topological space and $A\subseteq X$, show that $A\in \mathcal{C}_{\tau} $ , if and only if $ext(A)=X-A$ *

$\Rightarrow)$Suppose that $A\in \mathcal{C}_{\tau}$, by definition $A^{c}\in \tau$, then $int(A^{c})=A^{c}$ , I also have to $ext(A)=int(A^{c})$, hence $ext(A)=X-A$.

$\Leftarrow)$ Conversly, to show that $A$ is closed, we'll prove that $A^{c}$ is open.
Since $ext(A)=X-A$ by assumption, and $ext(A)=int(A^{c})$, thus implies $int(A^{c})=A^{c}$, that is to say $A^{c}$ is open.

Hence $A$ is closed.

**Note:** I have already shown that $ext(A)=int(A^{c})$

I would like to know if the demo is ok, and it is well written.

Comment: It could be written a little more smoothly, but it’s correct and understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct, although you could take fewer lines by writing it as follows:

> *Proof.* Let $A \subseteq X$. Then
> \begin{align}
> A \in \mathcal C_\tau 
> & \quad \textrm{if and only if} \quad X \setminus A \in \tau \\
> & \quad \textrm{if and only if} \quad \operatorname{int}(X \setminus A)  = X \setminus A \\
> & \quad \textrm{if and only if} \quad \operatorname{ext}(A)  = X \setminus A.
> \end{align}